# After upgrading to .Net 5, my entity framework web app throws an error when hitting the default controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I recently upgraded a .Net Core 2 Entity Framework web app to the latest .Net5.

I had to fix a ton of things to get it to build successfully. After finally getting it to build, when I try to run it locally in visual
studio, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has been registered.
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.get_TempData()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.View(String viewName, Object model)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.View(String viewName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.View()
   at LET.Panopto.Scheduler.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in G:\GamerMods\EFStart.AspNetCore.GamerMod\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 17
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

It looks like the error originates in my `HomeController.cs` file here:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In my Startup.cs file, during the upgrade I had to change this:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

to this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

It doesn't seem like a lot of people get this error, and the only one that people said worked was this:

```
 services.AddMvcCore(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddRazorViewEngine();
```

But I don't use Razor pages.

So I can't figure out why it's complaining. It worked fine before my .Net5 upgrade.

Has anyone encountered this?

thanks!

Comment: Do you still have a `services.AddMvc();` of some sort in `ConfigureServices`? It seems like you don't

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't...It seems like everything I read when upgrading from .Net Core 2.2 to .Net 5, said to remove it and replace it with something else.

Comment: What? No, whatever you were reading, stop :) there's too much BS out there, don't trust whatever they tell you. AddMvc is still needed if you don't want to add a few dozen services manually. If you were using only the WebAPI aspects of ASP.NET Core, then yes, there are better ways since 3.0

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh I see, so I need both lines?  The new `app.UseEndpoints` and the old `app.UseMvc`?

Comment: Those are different things. One thing is `services.AddMvc()` which injects dependencies needed by the framework, the other is `app.UseMvc`/`app.UseEndpoints` which register MVC middleware to the pipeline for handling http requests. Might be worth looking at official documentation at Microsoft Docs for doing the upgrade

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh I definitely consulted the MS docs...there was a lot to cover going from .NetCore 2.2 to .Net 5. I just must've missed something somewhere when trying to fix the bugs as I encountered them.